# python: python: scatter plot, The color of the Y axis makes the interval

Tags: matplotlib

I want to make intervals for each color, not to overlap on the Y axis.
How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
   ax.set_title(df["me"][0],fontsize=20)
   plt.xticks(rotation='vertical',fontsize=20)
   plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
   ax.set_ylabel(i,fontsize=40)
   ax.grid(True)
   plt.legend(loc='best',fontsize=20)

   fig.savefig(i+".png")
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the **error message** directly, thank you

Comment: It is completely unclear to me what you want.

Comment: It's difficult to know from you question what you want, but I *think* a [seaborn `stripplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html#seaborn.stripplot) could be what you're asking for. See the example where the `hue` variable is set to different locations on the x-axis

Comment: I have a lot of sorting colors. I use matplotlib and its scatter pattern overlaps the X axis. I want the dots of different colors on the X axis, each color does not overlap.
Is there a method of matplottlib?
I want Tom to understand what I express.
Thank